# How to loop through :eq for an unknown range using jquery?

Tags: jquery

How to loop through a jquery each loop using filter :eq for an unknown range?

for example, I would like to loop through the following:

```
$("#list li:eq("+ i +")").each(function(i)
{
      i++;
});
```

This code does not work

Comment: `$("#list li:eq("+ i +")")` this selects a single element, not multiple so you can loop with `each`. What do you want to achieve here?

Comment: I want to increment through the each loop using i++

Comment: Why use `i++` and not `.each` alone?

Comment: In other words, can :eq filter be use as an iterator?

Comment: I need to use :eq as a counter to go forwards or backwards

Comment: [Looking for something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/3eEbk/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#list li:eq("+ i +")").each(function(i)
{
      i++;
});
```

The above code has two obvious flaws:

1. you're trying to use `i` before you assign it a value, and
2. `$('#list li:eq(' + i + ')')` will only ever return one result (the `li` that's equal to whatever value `i` holds.

To iterate through the `li` elements, simply use:

```
$('#list li').each(function(i)
    {
        // do whatever you like in here.
    });
```

If you need to work only on elements that are equal to a particular value of `i`:

```
$('#list li').each(function(i)
    {
        if (i == 3){ // for example...
            // do whatever you like in here.
        }
    });
```

Or simply:

```
$('#list li').eq(3)
```

If you have specific requirements then please add those to the question, so that we can better help you with this.

Comment: In other words, :eq filter can not be use as an iterator?

Comment: You can use `eq()` within the `each()` method to perform actions based on the value of `i` or according to whatever other logic you execute, but `eq()` can only filter to *one* value, or none.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a counter to use for each item, the `each` method provides that as the first argument passed..

```
$("#list li").each(function(idx)
{
      // idx will be different for each li element processed..
});
```

`idx` will hold the *counter* (*the index*) of the currently processed `li` element from the matching set..

Answer (score 0):

Actually [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) can be used with a jQuery collection/array-thing. Also if you don’t need what jQuery’s .each() does for you, a simple loop might be better.

Here’s an example of how to group stuff using .filter(). Likely not the smartest way to do it:

```
var things = $('.things'),
    group_size = 3, grouped, index;

for (index = 0; index < things.length; index+=group_size) {

    grouped = things.filter( function(j) {
        return j >= index && j < index + group_size;
    });

    console.log( grouped );
}
```

You can play with that here : http://codepen.io/gabssnake/pen/ADBwp

If you really need .eq(), you can still use it with simple structures:

```
var things = $('.things'), index;

// mess with index, use in conjunction with eq

for (index = 0; index < things.length; index++) {
    things.eq( Math.pow(index,2) ).css({ 'color' : 'crimson' })
}
```

See it here : http://codepen.io/gabssnake/pen/hjrIa